# lua shell-less equivalent of `io.popen`

Tags: shell, io, lua

Lua's `io.popen` is useful for capturing stdout of a command, but it relies on `/bin/sh` for word-splitting, glob expansion, etc.

So I can do the following and it works great

```
-- this unfortunately uses /bin/sh
local command = "ls -1";

local ph = io.popen(command, "r")

while true do
   local line = ph:read()
   if line == nil then
      break
   end
   io.write("I read a line! " .. line .. "\n")
end

io.write("Done with line reading!\n")
```

Is there some function that's a thin wrapper around `spawn*` or `fork/exec*` that I can pass `{"ls", "-1"}` to in order to avoid the shell?

Comment: I'm just curious, why shell-less execution may be useful?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff because the command I want to invoke and read from is `curl --silent $SOME_URL` and I'd like to make sure that it doesn't do unexpected things when passed a shell metacharacter.

Comment: Something like `wget -qO - 'URL_with_metacharacters'`?  The only metacharacter to take care of is single quote: `wget -qO - 'URL with '\'' inside'`.  Does your problem solved?

Comment: http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.unistd.html

Comment: Why do languages keep defaulting to slow, insecure and fragile execution semantics while hiding any fast, secure and robust alternatives :(

Comment: so, I have an unbelievably narrow workaround for my use case. I can do `io.popen("custom_executable", "r")` where `custom_executable` is `#!/bin/sh` <newline> `exec curl --silent "$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"`. I'm still using the shell, but the thing I'm executing is a constant.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Doesn't your work-around also work without the custom executable? You can do io.popen('curl --silent "$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"'). The only remaining problem is that Lua cannot set environment variables...

Comment: Yes that's true. I structured it that way because I normally add `set -euf` and some other preambley stuff to my shell scripts.

Comment: If you're open to third-party modules, it looks like there is [subprocess](https://github.com/hishamhm/subprocess) (on [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org/modules/hisham/subprocess)) which does support `subprocess.popen(arg0, arg1, ...)`.